# Error in $A.getCallback() [erors is not defined] Callback failed: apex://createleaddata/ACTION$saveLead Failing descriptor: {c:createleaddatacmp}

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

component :

```
<aura:component  access="global"  controller="createleaddata" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" >

    <ltng:require styles="/resource/SLDS0122/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css"/>

    <aura:attribute name="newLead" type="Lead"
                    default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Lead',
                             'FirstName' : '',
                             'LastName' : '',
                             'Company': '',
                             'Phone' : '',
                             'Email':'',
                             'Title' :'' ,
                             }"/>






    <fieldset class="slds-box slds-theme--default slds-container--small">
        <legend id="leadform" class="slds-text-heading--smallslds-p-vertical--medium">
            lead Form
        </legend>


        <div>
            <lightning:input aura:id="leadid" label="First Name"
                             class="slds-input"
                             labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                             value="{!v.newLead.FirstName}"
                             />
        </div>



        <br/>    
        <div>
            <lightning:input aura:id="leadid" label="Last Name"
                             class="slds-input"
                             labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                             value="{!v.newLead.LastName}"
                             />
        </div>

        <br/>
        <div>  
            <lightning:input aura:id="leadid" label="Company"
                             class="slds-input"
                             labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                             value="{!v.newLead.Company}"
                             />
        </div>

        <br/>
        <div>
            <lightning:input aura:id="leadid" label="Phone"
                             class="slds-input"
                             labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                             value="{!v.newLead.Phone}" maxlength="12"
                             pattern="^(\s*\d\s*){12}$"
                             messageWhenPatternMismatch="Phone number is not valid/enter with country code also"
                             required="true" />
        </div>

        <br/>
        <div>
            <lightning:input aura:id="leadid" label="Email"
                             class="slds-input"
                             labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                             value="{!v.newLead.Email}"
                             pattern="^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$" 

                             messageWhenPatternMismatch="Please enter a valid Email Address"
                             required="true" />
            <!-- /\s+@\s+\.\s+/" -->


        </div>

        <br/> 
        <div>
            <lightning:input aura:id="leadid" label="Title"
                             class="slds-input"
                             labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                             value="{!v.newLead.Title}"
                             required="true"
                             />
        </div>


        <br/>

        <lightning:button aura:id="btnSubmit" variant="brand" label="Submit" 
                          onclick="{!c.createleadclick}"/>


        <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Cancel" 
                          onclick="{!c.handleCancel}"/>

    </fieldset>

</aura:component>
```

controller:

```
({
    createleadclick : function(component, event,helper) {
        //Getting the lead from page
        var newlec = component.get("v.newLead");
        //Assign server method to action variable
        var action = component.get("c.saveLead");
        //setting parameters for server method
        action.setParams({ 
            "ledrec": newlec
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            //Getting the response state
            var state = response.getState();

            //check if response is success
            console.log(state);
            var resultToast 
            $A.get("e.force:showToast");

            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                resultToast.setParams({"title": "Success!",
                                      "message":"The record has been created successfully."
                                     });

            }
            else if(state=="ERROR"){
                var errors=response.getError();
                if(erors){
                    if(errors[0]&& errors[0].message){
                        resultToast.setParams({"title":"Update Error",
                                               "message":"The update validation returned an error:"
                                               + errors[0].message 
                                              }); 
                    }
                } else{
                    resultsToast.setParams({
                        "title":"Update Unknown Error",
                        "message":"The update returned an error:" +state
                    });
                }
            }else{
                resultsToast.setParams({
                    "title":"Update unknown Error",
                    "message": "The update returnde an error:" +state
                });
            }
            resultsToast.fire();
            $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();

            //This closes the Action Window
            var dismissActionPanel=$A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
            dismissActionPanel.fire();
        });




        // Adding the action variable to the global action queue
        $A.enqueueAction(action)
    }
})
```

helper:

```
({
    handleCancel: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        cmp.set("v.newLead", false);
    }
})
```

apex class:

```
public  class createleaddata{
    @AuraEnabled

    public static void saveLead (Lead ledrec) {

       try{
            //Insert Lead Record
            upsert ledrec; 
        }catch(Exception e) {

            throw new AuraHandledException('something went wrong' +e.getMessage());

        }
        finally {
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi Asman, welcome to SFSE. Please **[edit]** your post to include relevant content like any error message in the body of your post, in addition to some text which explains what you are trying to achieve. Right now, the body of your question contains nothing but code, and while we strive to be terse, we do aim to have some actual text.

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo here.

```
var errors=response.getError();
if(erors){
```

It should be:

```
if(errors) // you were missing one r
```

Comment: ok i updated new errror getting

Comment: @AsmanSk At SFSE we limit the question to a [specific issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). You have right now by making an edit completely changed the original question and thus the answer here seems to be no more valid. Please open a new question with your current issue where you can refer this question and someone should be able to help you. I will rollback the edits so that the original question and answer are synced.